# R expression from `nls` fit?

Tags: r, expression, formula

I've fit a parametric function using `nls`, and now I want to print out an expression of the function with the learned parameters substituted back in.  For example:

```
x <- runif(100, 0, 100)
m <- 13 * exp(-0.05 * x^2) + 0.1 + runif(100,0,0.1)
mod <- nls(m ~ a*exp(-b*x^2)+c, start=list(a=10,b=0.1,c=0.1))
```

I can extract the formula and coefficients like so:

```
formula(mod)
# m ~ a * exp(-b * x^2) + c
coef(mod)
#           a           b           c 
# 13.00029360  0.04975388  0.14457936
```

But I don't see a way to substitute them back directly.  The only thing I can seem to do involves writing out the formula again:

```
substitute(m ~ a * exp(-b * x^2) + c, as.list(round(coef(mod), 4)))
# m ~ 13.0003 * exp(-0.0498 * x^2) + 0.1446
```

My ultimate goal here is to read a fitted `nls` object from an RDS file on disk and show its functional expression in an [org-mode](http://orgmode.org) document.

Comment: Brings up a good thing to request of the package author: provide a `nslfun` equivalent to `splinefun` and `approxfun` .

Comment: That would be nice.  In this case the package author is the R Core Team though, so I'm not optimistic it would be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
do.call(substitute, args=list(formula(mod), as.list(round(coef(mod),4))))
# m ~ 13.0097 * exp(-0.0501 * x^2) + 0.1536
```

It works because `do.call` first evaluates both of the arguments in `args` and only then uses `substitute()` to substitute the coefficients into the formula expression. i.e., the expression that `do.call()` ultimately evaluates looks like this one, as desired:

```
as.call(list(substitute, formula(mod), as.list(round(coef(mod),4))))
# .Primitive("substitute")(m ~ a * exp(-b * x^2) + c, list(a = 13.0097, 
# b = 0.0501, c = 0.1536))
```

Comment: Aha!  Yes, that works, thanks.  I kept trying to call `substitute()` twice, or `eval()`, or ....

Comment: @KenWilliams -- Funny. A double call to `substitute()` was my first thought as well, but even though it's the 'semi-official' solution to this problem (see the 4th code block in [this section of the R-lang manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Substitutions)) it's not nearly as easy to understand. In this case doing `eval(substitute(substitute(X, as.list(round(coef(mod),4))), list(X=formula(mod))))` works but is almost completely opaque!

Comment: I wrote `substitute2` to make this a bit easier: `pryr::substitute2(mod$call$formula, as.list(round(coef(mod), 4)))`.  It's frustrating that base R doesn't have a version of substitute with regular evaluation rules.

Comment: @hadley -- Thanks for the pointer to `pryr`. Yeah, an additional `quote` argument (like that in `do.call`), giving the user the option of evaluating the first argument, would be nice. Speaking of which --- could you check in R-chat for a recent conversation re: `devtools:create()` and let me know if I should make the idea there a formal "issue" on github?

Comment: Nice, `pryr` looks like it will come in handy.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien replied. I really don't like arguments that control how other arguments are interpreted - I think it's better to have separate functions.

Comment: I guess a third alternative is to make the default behavior be whichever one gives users more flexibility. Your `substitute2` is a better version of `substitute`, because its capabilities are a superset of `substitute()`'s. If you want it to behave like `substitute()`, just `quote` the first argument. Compare:  `substitute(x <- x + 1, list(x = 1))` and
 `substitute2(quote(x <- x + 1), list(x = 1))`.